# Git, bitbucket: Revert (Not Reset/Not Delete) Branch as initial Creation, IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket, git-revert

I would like to revert all changes made, as the branch was created!!!

Unfortunately, I can't delete the branch, or made a Reset.

Here a image on my IntelliJ.

[image]

Check the initial creation in terminal

[image]

Even, doing a revert I can see multiple files that made my branch containing aditional files..

[image]

**Is there an alternative to Reset... Revert all to initial creation?**
Why in bitbucket.org there are surplus files?

Answer (score 0):

Do not think of git storing files directly, think of it as storing changes made to the tree in the form of commits.

Even though you deleted those files from your working tree they can still be reconstructed by rewinding the git history.

If you look at the state of your tree at the head commit do you see the files? If you do see the files are they of size 0? If yes then they have been deleted but your git client is still allowing you to access the history of those deleted files easily.

What matters is the state of your tree at whatever commit you are working in. Git tracks the deleted files to allow you to go back to them if needed.

Now if you pushed sensitive information like passwords or keys to your git repository that will need to be removed from the git history using [this](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) procedure. DO NOT do this lightly, you can seriously damage your repository.

Comment: "*Git does not store files directly, it stores changes made to the working tree.*" Not true — Git stores files and calculates changes (diff).

Comment: @phd. Thanks for the feedback. I think I fixed my wording?

Comment: A little bit better but I do not understand why it's important to think about changes. To restore files/directories from commits there is no need to reconstruct history — just extract files/directories using `git checkout`, `git show`, `git restore`. As Git stores complete files there is no need to reconstruct them from changes, just extract from commits to the filesystem.

Comment: @phd The question from the asker I interpreted as "why are deleted files still showing in BitBucket".  The logic of storing changes and not files is important for understanding why what the asker is experiencing is happening.